# which id used for Android App mediation id or Publisher id

Tags: android, admob

i want to insert add in my app, which id i will use in android Application publisher id or mediation id ?

```
  <com.google.ads.AdView
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:id="@+id/ad"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="738a44d913034b9f"
     />
```

Answer (score 2):

A publisher ID is generated after adding a site/app and is used to request ads from the AdMob network. A publisher ID can request banners as well as interstitials, giving you the ability to use the same ID throughout your application to get AdMob ads. However, for better reporting, we still recommend that you use a different publisher ID for each ad placement.

A mediation ID is generated after creating a mediation placement. A mediation ID is used to retrieve the mediation configuration from the server so the AdMob SDK can make ad requests to other ad networks on your behalf. Unlike a site/app, a mediation placement requires you to define an ad format, for example a 320x50 banner. Trying to request an interstitial ad with a 320x50 banner mediation placement (and vice versa) will result in the error.

Google has explain same [Here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/04/know-your-admob-ids-publisher-vs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You use your publisher ID. :) Hope this helps!

Comment: ,i have already publish my apps with publisher id , somebody suggest me to use mediation id , if u confirm publisher id is best then give answer ..

Comment: and please also see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798450/admob-mediation-publisher-id-vs-mediation-id

Comment: and also this please ; then suggest me please 
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation